# Z-Axis blocked on MMB movement

Tags: 3d-view

While panning the orbit with the MMB, the movement of the start-up file cube, as well as of any other object, is restricted only to the X and Y axes, while the Z axis is blocked. What have I done wrong? I could always move my objects with the MMB along all axes. Trying to reset, I have downloaded the latest version v2.79b but unfortunately the problem persists. I've searched for an answer, but found only ones that relate to extrusion
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there blocked axis for rotating the viewport or rotating the object?

Comment: Are You sure it is not a HW problem? Rotating and resizing works well?

Comment: Mr Zak, the Z axis is blocked only when rotating the viewport.

Comment: Jan Matys, I've tried another mouse but nothing is changed. Rotating and scaling of objects work OK  on all axes.

Comment: If in viewport then this behaviour is normal as that's what Turntable orbit style means and it's by default unless changed. To change in User prefs > Input change Orbit Style.

Comment: Thank you Mr Zak for your help. Problem resolved.

Comment: @MrZak Could you add this as an answer please?

Comment: @Leander if you have time go ahead and add it instead

Comment: @MrZak Ok. I will do a Ctrl C, V.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be referencing the cameras movement in the viewport accessible via <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd>, as said in your comment.

> *Mr Zak, the Z axis is blocked only when rotating the viewport.*

By default, the *Viewport Orbit Style* is set to **Turntable**. For  a less restrictive Orbit Style, set it to **Trackball**.

> [The Orbit style sets] how Blender works when you rotate the 3D View by default when holding <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd>.
>
> **Turntable**
>   Rotates the view keeping the horizon horizontal.
>
> This behaves like a potter’s wheel or record player where you have two axes of rotation available, and the world seems to have a better definition of what is “Up” and “Down” in it.
>
> The drawback to using the Turntable style is that you lose some flexibility when working with your objects. However, you gain the sense of “Up” and “Down” which can help if you are feeling disoriented.
>
> **Trackball**
>   Is less restrictive, allowing any orientation.

<sup>*[Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/preferences/input.html?highlight=turntable#view-manipulation)*</sup>

To set the Orbit style to **Trackball**, open the **User Preferences** window <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> and go to the *Input* rider. Then click on the **Trackball** button.

[image: orbit style]

Answer (score 0):

try pressing the n key and checking that all the "lock" pictures are unlocked if it is locked, like in this picture [image: locked]

then you will not be able to move it in the z axis. if it is, just click it and it should change to the unlocked picture.

Comment: Triplex, thank you for your answer. All my location axes are unlocked, nevertheless, from now on I will always check this parameter.

Comment: could you try uploading your blend file

Comment: Triplex, as per Mr Zak’s answer, this behavior is normal. Thank you.